# ¿ Cual es la opción en Xcode para bloquear la orientación horizontal en una app?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Quiero que en mi app no se muestre la orientación horizontal.

En Xcode voy a 'General', 'Deployment Info' ,'Device Orientation'  pero no encuentro esa opción.

[image: Imagen opciones orientacion]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Landscape` significa orientación Horizontal (aunque literalmente en español es *paisaje*). `Portrait` significa vertical y `Upside Down` es vertical pero girado 180º

Esos dos checks de `Landscape` son para si giras el dispositivo hacia la izq o hacia la derecha.

Si los desmarcas no te dejará la orientación Horizontal.

---

> "Los tengo desmarcados pero aun así la aplicación me rota en Horizontal "

Si esto sucede comprueba el archivo `Info.plist` en la sección de `Supported interface orientations` y elimina aquellos items de `landscape` que no desees.

Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los tengo desmarcados pero aun así  la aplicación me rota en Horizontal

Comment: ¿Tienes en `Info.plist` en `Supported interface orientations` algún `Landscape item`? ej: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCwFH.png

Comment: Ok tenia los items de Landscape, ahora los he borrado y me funciona como quería. Gracias !

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta para que quede constancia de esto. De nada, me alegra ser de ayuda. Un saludo!